# XmlSerialization in C# - root element array

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I would like to de/serialize a XML-Document with type=array as root node.
The given xml structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <parties type="array">
        <party type="Person">
            <id>1</id>
            <lastname>Smith</lastname>
            <firstname>Peter</firstname>
            ...
        </party>
        <party type="Person">
            <id>2</id>
            <lastname>Smith</lastname>
            <firstname>Sarah</firstname>
            ...
        </party>
    <parties type="array">
```

C# Code looks like this:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("parties", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]       
public class Parties
{
    private ArrayList contacts = new ArrayList();


    public Parties()
    {

    }


    [XmlArray("parties"), XmlArrayItem("party", typeof(Person))]
    public ArrayList Contacts
    {
        get { return contacts; }
        set { contacts = value; }
    }
}
```

The resulting xml output is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <parties xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <parties>
            <party>
                <id>0</id>
                <lastname>Smith</last-name>
                <firstname>Peter</first-name>
            </party>
        </parties>
    </parties>
```

The problem is that I have 2 -tags now.
How can I specify array type for the root element? Any ideas how to fix it without changing the given xml schema?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
[XmlElement("party")]
public ArrayList Contacts
{
    get { return contacts; }
    set { contacts = value; }
}
```

Comment: +1; minor point - it only needs a `get` as long as the value is initialized correctly.

Comment: That solved the problem. @peter, consider marking this as the answer if it is the case.